# Is "natural" a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently created on this question: [What are some alternatives to under gravel filters for a 3000 gallon pond?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/what-are-some-alternatives-to-under-gravel-filters-for-a-3000-gallon-pond)

Comment: I was going to delete it, but I'm willing to be convinced that it has some usefulness.

Answer (score 10):

I think it's probably not... it's a word that has become essentially content-free, meaning whatever the speaker wants it to mean.

Comment: you beat me to it. I was going to say it was effectively meaningless.

Comment: I agree - absolutely meaningless.